# If T is an infinite subset of $\mathbb{N}$ show that there is a 1-1 mapping of T onto $\mathbb{N}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [An infinite subset of a countable set is countable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/107617/an-infinite-subset-of-a-countable-set-is-countable)
>   [Infinite subset of Denumerable set is denumerable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/143409/infinite-subset-of-denumerable-set-is-denumerable)
>   [Elementary set theory homework proofs](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/194230/elementary-set-theory-homework-proofs)

Like the title says: If T is an infinite subset of $\mathbb{N}$,  show that there is a 1-1 mapping of T onto $\mathbb{N}$.

I get the idea (like for evens and odds) but I don't know how to prove  it for ANY infinite subset of the natural numbers. Any advice?

Comment: One piece of advice: start with the smallest element of $T$.

Comment: You can see a mapping $f : T \to \mathbb{N}$ as a way of assigning a natural number to each element of $T$, namely $f(t)$. You could for example use the fact that the set $T$ has an order on it, the one provided by $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: So could I say that the smallest element of T maps to 1, the next smallest maps to 2, the next smallest to 3, and so on?

Comment: @William: That one’s a little more general, but it can certainly be adapted to this setting. I didn’t want to point to it, however, because it has a complete answer, and this question is homework.

Comment: It’s a little easier (in my opinion) to define the map in the other direction, but the basic idea is sound.

Comment: So how do I formalize all this? I was going to write: Let T be any infinite subset of $\mathbb{N}$. Since T is a subset of $\mathbb{N}$, T is ordered. Choose the smallest element of T and send it to 1, the next smallest element of T and send it to 2, etc. Maybe it was less complicated than I thought! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $T \subset \mathbb{N}$ is infinite, we can enumerate the elements of $T$ by $T=\{a_1,a_2,a_3,... \}$, where $i<j \Rightarrow a_i<a_j$. Can you see a natural function we can use to map onto $\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: the identity function? just send each number to itself?

Comment: No. What Tarnation wrote is "map each number (element) of T to the natural number matching its *index*". Some care is required here.

Comment: What Don said. If we use the map $f(a_i)=i$, we get a bijective map with the positive natural numbers.

Comment: @donantonio That's what I meant, I just wasn't saying it clearly. Thanks everyone for all your help! :)

Comment: Ok @AllisonCameron . Great example of why so many times students get low grades in exams: they meant something yet they wrote something meaning *anything else*. Good it happened to you here and not in class.

Answer (score 2):

It’s a little easier, I think, to define a bijection $f$ from $\Bbb N$ onto $T$ and use its inverse. Define it recursively: $f(0)=\min T$, and if $f(k)$ has been defined for all $k<n$, let $$f(n)=\min\Big(T\setminus\{f(k):k<n\}\Big)\;.$$ If you think a bit about what this construction is doing, you should be able to see that it must be yield a bijection, though you may still struggle a bit to write down a proof. Since the construction is recursive, try a proof by induction that the resulting function is onto.